# Navbar sticks to top before reaching scroll point and won't return until reload of page

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to implement a sticky navbar to a webpage I'm making.

Currently when I first enter any page the navbar will sit on its intended spot, but as soon as I scroll it snaps to the top and will stay there however I scroll. (sometimes it snaps back down when you scroll to the top)
The intended behavior is to stick whenever you scroll past the navbar position.

But if you reload the page once or twice it will start working just as intended.

Code is written in jquery:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    fixNavbar();
});

//Fixed navbar on scroll past navbar pos
function fixNavbar() {
    var navOffset = $(".navigation").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var nav = $(".navigation"), scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= navOffset) nav.addClass("nav-fix");
      else nav.removeClass("nav-fix");
    });
}
```

CSS is pretty simple: only a class with position: fixed;

**Here is the page in action:** http://aktersnurra.se
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Weird, I noticed that bug when I first visited the url, but now I cant get the nav bar to mess up

Comment: @KevinJantzer The image above his navigation bar is now in your browser cache and therefore much faster loaded which means there is no difference anymore between DOM loading and complete page loading. Also see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image on top of the navigation bar is still loading when you set up your scroll event.

This means that the `navOffset` often gets incorrect values.

You have to replace your

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

into

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
```

Which waits untill the whole page including images is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the issue.
I didn't know document.ready didn't count certain items. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your navOffset is getting the wrong value at times

[image]